# Mysql remote connect CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, port, phpmyadmin

i have problem with mysql remote connect.
In my.cnf have: `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` and `#skip-networking.`
In users mysql have special user `remote@%`
And still not working.

If i try: `nmap -p 3306 remote.ip.com`

Output is:

```
PORT       STATE      SERVICE
3306/tcp   filtered   mysql
```

It is way ?

**Thanks,
Regards.**

Comment: Do you have either `iptables` or `firewalld` blocking the connection?

Comment: @doneal24 firewalld -- is off, and iptables i add rule

Comment: show us what give ```netstat -pnlt|grep mysql```. If we see a mysql process listening, then you have a firewall issue, otherwise you have a mysql configuration issue. You _need_ to see the port "open" in order to be able to connect to.

Comment: `filtered` indicates a firewall.

Comment: You should not open MySQL port to the public internet for security reasons. Use SSH port forwarding instead.

Comment: @Dominix  netstat -pnlt|grep mysql
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1577/mysqld

Comment: you certainly have a firewall issue. Maybe look for nftables based firewall.

Comment: The firewall does not necessarily have to be on the host itself.

Comment: @vidarlo OP's post on Ask Ubuntu is closed because it's offtopic there.

Comment: Try drawing a network diagram of how users connect to the database. There may be other network devices between them and the server.